# Broken images in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, image, mongodb, meteor, imagesource

Best method for clearing broken images from a database. I have 30,000+ image entries in my mongodb database however many have become broken over time. I want to only return images that aren't broken on the server side. What would be the best method to find all the broken images and add a parameter or delete the broken images from the database?

Currently I am returning all the images to the frontend and doing and hiding on the 'onerror' attribute. Should I export and iterate over all the images somehow and get an export of the image ids?  Are there better options or what can I use to do this? Just looking for advice.

Comment: I had a problem with image corruption in mongo, and dumping the data and restoring it fixed the problem

Comment: You could write a cron job that once a month (or longer) attemps to load every image using `HTTP.get()` and on failure removes the url from the collection.

Comment: What are you storing in your database for the images (a filepath to an image, a URL, a binary image, an API reference, ...)? How can you tell an image is "broken" (i.e. is that corrupt / missing / ...)?

Comment: Mikkel - the file urls aren't corrupt. The file destinations no longer exists.
MichelFloyd - I may try that but it shouldn't occur in the future.  I may actually do that job once though if I find that to be the best solution for a large amount of files
@Stennie I am storing a URL and moved across to a new server and found that the previous server had temporary upload problems at some point and a some of the files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Blaze template event handlers to catch image load errors, then flag the image as failed, or just delete it. Self cleaning and always running...

```
Template.ImageLoader.events({
  //TODO: possibly add an extra class name on the img tag, to make sure you only catch errors from your collection.
  'error img': function(event, template) {
    const url = event.currentTarget.src;
    //TODO: find the image in your collection, using the url
    //TODO: perform cleanup (flag or delete)
    alert(`error loading image ${url}`);
  }
});
```

I would suggest adding an error counter to your collection and `$inc` it each time a loading error occurs. Once the load error count reaches a certain number, delete it.